# How to make a function with if condition for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I want to make a function that can append a new line of text to a .txt file with if condition.
I'm not good at code. Can someone explain to me how to create a function in python?

ex : given a table like this

| text | similarity | polarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDD | 0.6 | POSITIF |
| ASDAS | 0.4 | NEGATIF |
| ASGAS | 1.0 | POSITIF |

So , i want to make a function with if condition. The condition is like this :
If the value in column dataframe ['similarity'] is greater than 0.5 , and the value in other column dataframe ['polarity'] is "POSITIF". Then , i want to append a new line of text to a .txt file.
Can someone explain how to make that possible?
I've tried myself , but i guess it's a total mess

```
if (df['similarity'] > 0.5) & df['polarity'].str.contains('POSITIF').any():
    with open("text.txt","a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("text appended \n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to do exactly.

If you need to loop over all the rows, use`iterrows` (Warning, it is slow!):

```
with open("text.txt","a") as myfile:
    for key, row in df.iterrows():
        if (row['similarity'] > 0.5) and ('POSITIF' in row['polarity']):
            myfile.write("text appended \n")
```

If you want to append the line if any row matches both conditions:

```
if (df['similarity'].gt(0.5) & df['polarity'].str.contains('POSITIF')).any():
    with open("text.txt","a") as myfile:
        myfile.write("text appended \n")
```

Comment: anyway. I have another question. Can we add a new line of text above a spesific word in text file?
ex : i want to add "text appended" below "here's the text" in this .txt file :
"here's the text \n
can someone exp? \n
thanks"

can we possibly do it?

Comment: Maybe open a new question with all details (with the `python` tag)